# Drupal Module - Mailing List, cannot export list, get browser error

Tags: emails

I've just started using the mailing list module, but when I put it on my live site I get an error when I try to export the list of entries. I did get an actual Drupal error which is

```
    Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

this put an entry in my Log which I followed up on the net and found this page http://drupal.org/node/1206916 entry #11 led me to a link which should fix this, I tried this, but now I just get a Browser failure saying it cannot locate the file.

any ideas? or is there a better mail module?

Comment: If you are getting errors from a certain module, there may be a bug in the module and you should report the error in the module's [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/mailing_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble with the module you are using, there are other mail-type modules available.

- [MailChimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) - Module to utilize subscriptions/emails with [mailchimp.com](http://www.mailchimp.com/)
- [Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) - Publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers (still in Alpha)
- [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) - Complete Subscriptions/Notifications Framework aiming at extendability and scalability (still in Alpha)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have a hard time locating appropraite modules within the Drupal.org pages. Will check out these modules I have basic needs, I hope one will serve. thanks.